# How to Integrate Twitter Oauth as like Facebook?

Tags: android, android-layout, twitter, android-emulator, android-widget

I am new to integrating Twitter. I have implemented Twitter in my application with this code:

```
         // Create file 
            File picture = new File(APP_FILE_PATH + "/myAwesomeDrawing.png");  
            // Create TwitPic object and allocate TwitPicResponse object 
            TwitPic tpRequest = new TwitPic("username", "password"); 
            TwitPicResponse tpResponse = null;  
            // Make request and handle exceptions                            
            try {         
                tpResponse = tpRequest.uploadAndPost(picture, "Image Uploaded from My AndroidDrawing App...");

                } 
            catch (IOException e) {         
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
            catch (TwitPicException e) {         
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }  
            // If we got a response back, print out response variables                               
            if(tpResponse != null)         
                tpResponse.dumpVars();
```

All works fine here. But here I have to add the username and password programmatically. Is there any other way to use the Twitter integration as like Facebook OAuth to integration?

I need to know how Twitter OAuth is checked, and if the User is not login then it will ask for the username and password in its in built window.

Comment: Yes you can you Twitter Oauth in following Link
[TwitterWithOauth](http://android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application)

Comment: Ohh, Thanks Hardik Gajjar from Ahmedabad. and from p***x. Nice to meet you. I will accept while i will get proper result.

Comment: Ok. Have you implemented that sample project? As because i have done it step by stem as mention. But got error like your api key is wrong.

Comment: I have Successfully Copy paste that key but still got that error. Please check in your case and let me tell. And For more information see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080043/why-i-am-getting-this-error-while-integrating-twitter-demo

Comment: And Yes another thing is, I want to upload photo in twitter as like tweet photo in twitter. So will it be possible threw this OAuth Demo?

Comment: Yes we can TwitPic by Oauth Demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If caguilar187's code link's are not enough, then here are few more links for code help:

1. http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/08/08/improved-twitter-oauth-android/
2. http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/
3. http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/312.html
4. **Best suggested:** http://android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application
5. **One more suggest:** http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html
6. **Post on Twitter:** http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/
7. **GitHub Link:** https://github.com/brione/Brion-Learns-OAuth

Comment: if you will ask for demo then you will get link only... Or else point out the problem where you got stucked...

Comment: :Well i have searched all that site and finished the task.

Comment: Thanks for the Links. be in Contect DShah. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hope below link help you:-

**Below link show you how to generate key with Twitter and other social media**

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/wiki/Twitter

**Now below link is source code where u find out source code**

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

here are a few they all use signpost to do it.

**Signpost**:
http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/

**Blogs**
http://dev.bostone.us/2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/#awp::2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/

http://blog.copyninja.info/2010/09/android-oauth-authentication-with.html

http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/wiki/TwitterAndSignpost

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I want to Upload the Photo on twitter as like tweet with Image on twitter. So will it be possible with this OAuth sample example ?

Comment: to do that you just need to follow the examples for posting a status update but instead use the following api call to twitter. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Comment: I have see this link. There is doc for thr twitter4j to upload photo on status. But still i want so me source code in android so that i can get help to fit it in my Application.