# Android twitter integration and sending tweets programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am trying to implement Twitter integration in Android, and also to send tweets programmatically. I  searched a lot on the Internet, but I am not getting the proper example for twitter integration and sending the tweet. If any one has a proper example of Android Twitter integration and sending the tweet, please share the link.

Comment: Have you look at this my question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102935/is-there-any-demo-to-integrate-twitter-oauth-as-like-facebook

Answer (score 2):

I used this project to post message on facebook , twitter and linkedin. You can try this :

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/

Answer (score 1):

Same problem i had seen when I'm doing same thing but my searching is stopped with below link:-

**Below link show you how to generate key with Twitter and other social media**

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/wiki/Twitter

**Now below link is source code where u find out source code**

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Twitter OAuth integration in Android

Find further code and implementation here: https://github.com/browep/Android-OAuth-

http://responsiveandroid.com/2012/03/15/twitter-oauth-integration-in-an-android-app.html

Answer (score 0):

First Generate the **CUSTOMER KEY** AND **CUSTOMER SECRET** then  add the twitter4j jar into your project.
then i guess this link will help u as a simple example http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/08/08/improved-twitter-oauth-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/), here are some [examples](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html).